# Android and iOS webview not loading HTML, using AJAX, after playing embedded video

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, webview

I have an Ebook web app with a jquery carousel plugin (Royalslider) that preloads HTML component files(image, HTML, CSS), using AJAX, in the succeeding page containers when the user swipes to the next page. This Ebook web app is loaded in a native app webview, both iOS and Android. In some of the pages, I place video triggers to play a video overlay (YouTube, MOVIDEO). I'm testing this in mobile devices (iPhone and Android phones)

The pre loading of the HTML components work perfectly fine until I play the embedded video in the page container. For example, I play an embedded video in page 2, the mobile video player loads, plays and I close the video. However, when I swipe to the succeeding pages, the preloading of the HTML components doesn't occur so I end up with empty pages in the page containers of the carousel. This issue occurs only in the webview of the native app. I tried it on an external mobile browser and it doesn't happen.

Is there a mime-type or data-type that I need to set again after loading the video? Why won't the AJAX fetch of HTML contents work after playing the video? Is this an "origin" issue after loading the videos?

I'm not familiar with the Android and iOS webviews. I'm putting this e-book web app as a 3rd party solution provider.